# error message: Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios

I KNOW what this error message

"Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation"

means. I have duplicate symbols.

What I DON'T know is what "use - v to see invocation" means.

How do I actually use -v? In Terminal or where? Please someone, give me an example of its actual use.

Comment: This message can mean a lot of things (not only duplicate symbols). In Xcode, go to the last tab in the left panel (the one on the right) and select the last build. You will find a more detailed explanation of the build failure. Paste it here if you don't understand it.

Comment: Yes. From the terminal. If you are using an IDE, you can probably configure it so that it runs with the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.
I found a way to get the error info: Control-click on the red error indicator (at left), then select Show Error Log, which gives the complete information.
(Meanwhile the "Use -v" message remains useless.)